Need help in identifying- analog Hall sensor with the numbers 958409 (Added: Actually 95B)
I have found the following analog Hall sensor on some old BLDC motors I salvaged. I'm hoping to replace them with digital ones, but I am unable to find any specs on the current ones.
A picture of a three pin part that is perpendicular to the PCB it is mounted to. On the part are the numbers 4, 5, 8 or B, 4, 0, and 9, and what appears to be a dash at the end:

I have tried looking up the numbers visible (958409,) but I can't find it.

Allegro and Honeywell are likely suppliers. Your title is incorrect.

Could the 8 be a B? So 95B409?

It would seem you are both correct. I'll leave the title as is so the answers still make sense.

There's half a chance that it's this one from Honeywell: -

Image from MAGNETIC SENSOR IC SELECTION CHART.
You can purchase this part from Octopart: -



I have tried looking up the numbers visible 958409

I read the identity as starting with 95B, rather than 958. The Honeywell MAGNETIC SENSOR IC SELECTION CHART has some parts with a standard label of 95B.
Found the Honeywell SS490 SERIES Linear Hall-effect Sensor ICs on a distributor website for the Honeywell SS495B which appears to be an active product.

@Colin the top line of the device marking looks like 95B which matches a Standard Label column in TABLE 2. LINEAR SENSOR ICS in the "MAGNETIC SENSOR IC SELECTION CHART" linked in the answer. The bottom line of the device marking in the picture in the question is 409- which could potentially be a manufacturing lot number. From the Honeywell documentation so far haven't found the significance of the bottom line of the device marking.
